# Knockout mapping complex object

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

For example, we have complex object:

```
var complex = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {c1: 1, c2: 2}};
```

We want it to make observable:

```
var observableComplex = ko.mapping.fromJS(complex);
```

Question: why we get c variable not observable? I was seen somewher in manuals, that this is done by design and I want to know why?

```
a - observable,
b - observable
c - object:
  c1 - observable
  c2 - observable
```

Comment: Yes this is by design. And probably you should ask the authors about the reason behind this decision...

Comment: @nemesv Not to be argumentative, but ...if you're not the author, how is it that you know this is by design?

Answer (score 0):

There is no object for 'c' that can be mapped...if you want it to be observed, you need to create a custom mapping for it and define your object.

ie

```
var Complex = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.c = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.c);
}

var CustomMapping = {
    create: function(options) {
        return new Complex(options.data);
    }
}

var observableComplex = ko.mapping.fromJS(complex, CustomMapping);
```

In short, this creates a new Complex object then digs in and maps the data for 'c' as observableComplex is created. For my custom objects, I have quite a few situations like this for dealing with nested objects.

Comment: I know that. But why is done that way? Person, who programmed mapping plugin, why is he programmed that way? He detects complex objects and for some reason leaves it un-observable... So, should I use something like your solution or leave it as it is?

Comment: You'll need to do it like I mentioned. One way or another, a default mapping won't dig down into complex objects...you'll need to handle it. In the long run, it's better to have the control over your objects. I can't think of any reason where I'd just pass in a crazy big object and not want to define how it's handled anyways...

Comment: Because that "crazy big object" is defined server side and I know how it looks and I don't want repeat myself and redefine it in client side.

Comment: Then you'll never have granular control over it...nor will another coder be able to come along and decipher your objects and their bindings properly. It's good practice to declare your objects...however redundant it may feel.

Comment: ko.mapping does exactly that: decipher my json object. Yes, sometimes there is a need to make some customization.