# Bind complex JSON object using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm brand new to using Knockout.js and have just installed/instantiated a `ViewModel` binding using `ko.mapping.js` only to find that I get a partial binding.

Using the example code listed below we see that the binding works for the simple data but not the complex data in the JSON object.
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrbilljsf/Pd66y/)

Complex JSON object:

```
 var json = {
    "a": "A",
    "b": [{
           "b1": "B1",
           "b2": "B2",
           "b3": [{ "one": "One", "two": "Two"}]
         }],
    "c": "C"
 }
```

HTML Elements to bind to:

```
<div data-bind="text: a"></div>
<div data-bind="text: b.b1"></div>
<div data-bind="text: c"></div>
```

Javascript ViewModel/binding:

```
var vm = {};    
vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Have I missed something?

In Knockout.js, is it possible to bind a complex JSON object to a  viewmodel using knockout.mapping.js?

**If not**, using this example ...**how can we bind this complex JSON object using knockout.js**?

The closest existing StackOverflow post I've been able to find is this one, [Knockout mapping complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427555/knockout-mapping-complex-object)
and I've tried for hours now utilizing multiple approaches and have been unsuccessful in being able to you the `ko.mapping.js` to do this binding.

And unfortunately the Knockoutjs.com documentation (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) doesn't cover whether or not this is even possible with the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ko.mapping.js handles simple as well as complex object implicitly. Actually there is problem in binding which is used to access nested object.

As you see property b is an array so ko.mapping will convert it into observableArray.so binding will be like this :-

```
<div data-bind="text: a"></div>
<div data-bind="text: b()[0].b1"></div> //As b is array
<div data-bind="text: c"></div>
```

Below you can see the object after mapping.

```
{
"a": "A",
"b": [
    {
        "b1": "B1",
        "b2": "B2",
        "b3": [
            {
                "one": "One",
                "two": "Two"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"c": "C",
"__ko_mapping__": {
    "ignore": [],
    "include": [
        "_destroy"
    ],
    "copy": [],
    "observe": [],
    "mappedProperties": {
        "a": true,
        "b[0].b1": true,
        "b[0].b2": true,
        "b[0].b3[0].one": true,
        "b[0].b3[0].two": true,
        "b[0].b3": true,
        "b": true,
        "c": true
    },
    "copiedProperties": {}
}
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pd66y/7/)

Comment: The visualization of the mapping is very helpful as well.